# iOS TrueDepth frame to point cloud

Tags: ios, 3d, metal, point-clouds, face-id

I'm trying to obtain a 3D point cloud from a single TrueDepth frame (AVDepthData / CVPixelBuffer) in iOS.
I came across the official documentation however I don't seem to be able to find the last missing piece: [Streaming Depth Data from the TrueDepth Camera](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/streaming_depth_data_from_the_truedepth_camera)

This code perfectly renders the point cloud that I'm interested in but I can't find out how to obtain the world coordinates in meters from it and store them as a pcd file.

Is there a way to read out all of the 3D points of the metal depth texture or is this the wrong approach?
If so where would I start from here?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the shader function `vertexShaderPoints` take a look at the following:

```
uint2 pos;
pos.y = vertexID / depthTexture.get_width();
pos.x = vertexID % depthTexture.get_width();

// depthDataType is kCVPixelFormatType_DepthFloat16
float depth = depthTexture.read(pos).x * 1000.0f;

float xrw = (pos.x - cameraIntrinsics[2][0]) * depth / cameraIntrinsics[0][0];
float yrw = (pos.y - cameraIntrinsics[2][1]) * depth / cameraIntrinsics[1][1];

float4 xyzw = { xrw, yrw, depth, 1.f };
```

Refactor this calculation for your point cloud writer and I think you'll have what you're looking for.

Comment: Is it possible to access `cameraIntrinsics` matrix from within a .swift file? This example shows usage of .metal files but I need to access same values from my swift 5 application.

Comment: Yes it is, see the documentation here:https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera